# $1000000 \div 81=12345.67$ - why?

Tags: number-theory

Is this a coincidence that the digits are ordered  "nicely" or is there a number theory explanation? The exact value is:

$$1000000\div 81 = 12345.\overline{679012345}$$

Comment: This [Numberphile](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=daro6K6mym8) video talks about a similar (similar = interesting) pattern that arises from a different number.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$\frac1{81}=\frac19\frac19=(0.1111111\dots)(0.1111111\dots);$$
start multiplying it out by hand.

Comment: +1 for managing to succinctly answer the question in a meaningful way and simultaneously relate it to another quirky digit-trick.

Comment: Wow! Thanks! Great answer